# Is LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL deprecated?

Tags: python, django

I am using a mixin to check if a user is authenticated before allowing them into a class based formview. It works fine, but if the user is not authenticated it redirects them to the default login path of '/accounts/profile/'. According to the documentation this path can be overriden with the use of LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL or maybe even LOGIN_URL in settings.py. However, [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL) states that both of these are deprecated as of Django 1.8 and will be removed in Django 1.10. I am on 1.9 and would like to future proof my code. How can I specify what the login url or login redirect url is using a non deprecated method? I would even be willing to abandon the mixin approach, but how would I perform a manual check upon the request of a class based view and then redirect away from it if the check fails?

```
class LoginCheckMixin(UserPassesTestMixin):
    def test_func(self):
        if 'id_token' in self.request.session:
            return validate_google_token(self.request.session['id_token'])
        else:
            return False


class RegistrationFormView(LoginCheckMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'registration/registration_form.html'
    form_class = RegistrationForm
    success_url = 'results'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` are not deprecated.

In Django 1.8, it is deprecated to use the a dotted Python path as the values for these settings. Say your login url is:

```
url('^login/$', views.login, name='login')
```

The following is deprecated,

```
LOGIN_URL = 'path.to.views.login'
```

but you can still use

```
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'  # hardcoded url
```

or

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login'  # the name of the url pattern
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. It worked great with a hardcoded URL. When I tried the url pattern it did not work. url(r'^$', views.login, name='login') LOGIN_URL = 'login' resulted in: NoReverseMatch
Reverse for 'login' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: Using the url pattern name should work. Are you using a namespace to include the urls? If so you should do `LOGIN_URL = '<namespace>:login'`.